# How to say "short/little time is left"?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, expressions

What is the proper way to say that very *little/short* time is left for something?

For example, when there are very few days left before the exams start. I don't want to mention *days,* but *time,* in my sentence. Something like ***there is very little time left for the exams***.

Comment: This question could use more context. One could say "time is running out." However, when taking an exam, the proctor will often explicitly say "30 minutes before the exam ends" or something similar.

Comment: "There's very little time left _before_ the exams." _For the exams_ would mean that there was barely enough time in which to take the exams.